# Xamarin.Forms: Image.GestureRecognizers causes exception on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am using the latest version of `Xamarin.Forms`. My page has a `ListView` which shows `ViewCells` containing an `Image`. Now I would like to react to a tap on these images. Therefore, I added this code

```
<Image Grid.Column="1" Source="download_cloud.png" WidthRequest="32" HeightRequest="32">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
           <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="SynchronizeItem_Clicked"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

This works flawless on `Android`. Sadly, this is not working on `iOS` but causes an exception (`Object reference not set to an instance`). The strange thing is, that when I add this `TapGestureRecognizer` to a `Label` which is displayed next to the `Image` everything is working perfectly. 
So, is this a bug in `Xamarin.Forms` on `iOS` or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: This is the stacktrace:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.EventTracker.LoadRecognizers () [0x0005d] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\EventTracker.cs:373 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.EventTracker.OnElementChanged (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementChangedEventArgs e) [0x0004e] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\EventTracker.cs:439 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e) [0x00020] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:279 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer`2[TView,TNativeView].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e) [0x00000] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\ViewRenderer.cs:85 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS
.ImageRenderer.<>n__0 (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e) <0x13780f3f0 + 0x0005a> in <13d193f5a21b4e309afc67e0a5508db5>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ImageRenderer+<OnElementChanged>d__2.MoveNext () [0x000d6] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ImageRenderer.cs:70 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.2/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.2/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018 
  at UIKit.UIKitSynchronizationContext+<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users
/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIKitSynchronizationContext.cs:24 
  at Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSAction.cs:163 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at SMSIP2.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\Users\Roland\Source\Repos\SMSIP2\SMSIP2\SMSIP2.iOS\Main.cs:12 
2018-01-28 10:06:25.613 SMSIP2.iOS[73968:6382644] Unhandled managed exception:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object (System.NullReferenceException)
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.EventTracker.LoadRecognizers () [0x0005d] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\EventTracker.cs:373 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.EventTracker.OnElementChanged (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementChangedEventArgs e) [0x0004e] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\EventTracker.cs:439 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e) [0x00020] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:279 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer`2[TView,TNativeView].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e) [0x00000] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\ViewRenderer.cs:85 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Plat
form.iOS.ImageRenderer.<>n__0 (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e) <0x13780f3f0 + 0x0005a> in <13d193f5a21b4e309afc67e0a5508db5>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ImageRenderer+<OnElementChanged>d__2.MoveNext () [0x000d6] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ImageRenderer.cs:70 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.2/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.2/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018 
  at UIKit.UIKitSynchronizationContext+<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] i
n /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIKitSynchronizationContext.cs:24 
  at Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSAction.cs:163 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at SMSIP2.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\Users\Roland\Source\Repos\SMSIP2\SMSIP2\SMSIP2.iOS\Main.cs:12 
2018-01-28 10
```

and this is the callback:

```
void SynchronizeItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs ee)
{

}
```

**Edit2**: When I use this code somewhere else and not in the `ListView` it is working on `iOS`, too.

**Edit3**: I fixed this problem now - but the solution is very strange and I do not know at all, why it is working. But here we go: My `CellView` contained a `Grid` in which I wanted to place my `Image`. This is not working. What is working instead is: place the `Image` inside a `StackLayout` and place this `StackLayout` in the `Grid`. This looks just like the code without the additional `StackLayout` and suddenly the `GestureRecognizer` works. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

**Edit4**: Apparently this is not a great solution as this `Command` of the `GestureListener` is now also executed sometimes when you click on the `ViewCell` instead of the `Image`. So this is no real solution.

Comment: what does SynchronizeItem_Clicked look like?  What does the stack trace for the exception show?

Comment: Will you still get an exception if you make SynchronizeItem_Clicked method empty temporarily?

Comment: @Jason I added the code and the stacktrace as an edit.

Comment: @Vahid Yes, the code of the `SynchronizeItem_Clicked` method does not change anything.